# setting different margins for Pylatex sections

Tags: formatting, pdftex, margins, python, pylatex

I would like to set different margins for different sections of a Pylatex document (incl header, sections and subsections). I'm new to latex

I am currently setting my geometry options as follows, using this minimal example. I tried to change the margins of subsequent sections by setting the geometry options, which didn't work:

```
from pylatex import Command, Document, Section

geometry_options = {"tmargin": "0.5in", "lmargin": "0in", "bmargin": "0.5in", "rmargin": "0in"}
doc = Document(geometry_options=geometry_options, fontenc='T1')

with doc.create(Section('Section1')) as Sect1:
    Sect1.append('some text')

with doc.create(Section('Section2')) as Sect2:
    Sect2.append('some more text')
    Sect2.geometry_options = Command({'margins':'1in'})

doc.generate_pdf("testoutput", clean_tex=False)
```

This is the corresponding latex output:

```
\documentclass{article}%
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}%
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}%
\usepackage{lmodern}%
\usepackage{textcomp}%
\usepackage{lastpage}%
\usepackage[tmargin=0.5in,lmargin=0in,bmargin=0.5in,rmargin=0in]{geometry}%
%
%
%
\begin{document}%
\normalsize%
\section{Section1}%
\label{sec:Section1}%
some text

%
\section{Section2}%
\label{sec:Section2}%
some more text

%
\end{document}
```

How can I change the margins within the document in the Pylatex code?

Answer (score 1):

You expect pylatex to translate

```
Sect2.geometry_options = Command({'margins':'1in'})
```

to something like

```
\newgeometry{margins=1in}
```

But probably pylatex has no idea of geometry.

Read the geometry manual (cmd: `texdoc geometry`), section User interface. Probably `\savegeometry`and `\loadgeometry`will become your friends, *if* you can pass the necessary commands from your pylatex file to LaTeX. I have no idea how to do that, but to judge from your code you seem to know such things.